# STM32 FSMC Timing Computation

Tags: stm32, timing, timing-analysis

I'm working on FSMC protocol of STM32 micro controller The formula for calculate FSMC timing is below, but I have a hard time understanding it.  [From ST Application Note](http://www.st.com/st-web-ui/static/active/en/resource/technical/document/application_note/CD00201397.pdf)
[image: one]

[image]

Can someone walk be through the derivation of the values shown for Address Setup time, Address Hold time, and Data Setup time?

Comment: What are the "formulas described above"??  Do you have an actual question?

Comment: the problem is how to get these value "Address setup time: 01", "Address hold time: 0x0", "Data setup time: 0x5"